# How to prevent Visual Studio from building the project every time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

When I right-click on a project and select Build, it builds it every time despite the fact that I just built it and the project is not out of date.

I've followed the instructions in the [winning answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063194/visual-studio-builds-projects-every-time-i-run), but that didn't resolve my problem.

I've also gone and made sure that Options/Project and Solutions/Build and Run settings were all correct.  I turned on Detailed build output but didn't see anything obvious.  The output is here: [Part 1](https://pastebin.com/H6cDK3pk) and [Part 2](https://pastebin.com/iJwbgu4a).  The project itself if [here](https://pastebin.com/MjtEehkp).

The only thing that's suspicious is the following:

```
1>Project file contains ToolsVersion="4.0". This toolset may be unknown or missing
```

There is no `ToolsVersion=4.0` in the project file.

Comment: what's the .net framework your project was originally created for? which version of visual studio?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but in the log says: `Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.` | `Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped`. About references: `Did not copy from file "obj\$Reference" to file "bin\$Reference" because the "SkipUnchangedFiles" parameter was set to "true" in the project and the files sizes and timestamps match.` Your project wasn't rebuild.

Comment: @FrancescoB. Not sure.  It's at least 15 years old.  I am assuming .NET 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone runs into a similar problem.  The problem was that some files in the project (binaries and other non c# files) were set to `Content/Copy Always`.  I changed them to `Content/Copy if Newer` and that fixed the issue.

Comment: I remember that I had the same problem a lomg time ago. When going through the build log, you should be able to trace this. Sometimes a tool helps too, to view the log in a structured manner, like msbuild log viewer http://msbuildlog.com).

Comment: @Styxxy The trick was to set the build log to `Diagnostic` instead of `Detailed`.  Detailed mode didn't reveal any of the information I was looking for.

Comment: Indeed! Now you say it, it rings a bell. Though, when troubleshooting I generally put the logs on diagnostics :-).